# Extending Devise Registration Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise, controller

I have an `Accounts` model set up with Devise. Devise uses a few attributes (such as email, password etc.) but I have a few other attributes that I made. On sign up, I'd like to set them up in a way.

How can I extend the registration controller? I understand that I need to actually create a new controller like this:

```
class AccountsController < Devise::RegistrationController
  def create
    super
  end
end
```

Can I just add my code right after `super`? I think it would be too late as the resource would have already been saved. What's the best way to do this?

If I were to write create from scratch, how would I know that I didn't miss anything that Devise does?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rewrite the controller from scratch for full control, start with the registration_controller.rb [Source Code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) and make your changes as necessary.

Telling devise to use your custom controller is as simple as changing the route:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/custom_controller" }
```

Comment: Is that the best way to extend it? It's just two attributes that I need to add. Also, how do you tell Devise that I have a new controller (so that it doesn't use the one in the gem)?

Comment: @Darksky Best? I'm not exactly sure.  You could give it a try and see how 'dirty' it feels.  I updated my answer with an explanation on telling devise about your new controller.

Comment: what if i only want to override without recreating it all - how can one do that?

Answer (score 15):

According to the [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers), yes, just like Josh's answer, you would change the controller. Although, you don't have to start completely from scratch. Take a look at the documentation.

You can generate the controller so you are able to add customizations:

```
Example: rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

So, you could run the following for your Users scope:

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

This gives you the controllers in a folder located here:
**app/controllers/users**

Then, tell your routes file to use that controller. Update your devise route to look like this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

And finally, copy over all the views. If you haven't genereated the views yet, you'll need to do so. The controller has changed, so your views will need to as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fields for user supplied information there's no need to extend controller.
If you want to add those automatically, there's no reason **not** to do it in model! (unless it depends on session or request)

In 1st case, see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

You should change DEvise controller ONLY if you intend to change signup flow.

Comment: But doing `before_save` and calling a method that sets up some values in the model breaks devise and sign up does not work properly.

Comment: It wouldn't let me login and signing up redirected to the main page (w/o authenticating user & pass). I ended up setting the default values in the database instead.